# Multi-Module Vaadin project where routed views are located in independent modules

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I'm playing around the idea of a very huge vaadin application, which consists of a skeleton (providing the ui framework) and hundreds of functional units (providing the specific vaadin views).

The main architectural point is to let the skeleton be **agnostic** about the functional units, so not a single java dependency to a functional unit should be injected into skeleton. Every single functional unit has to be in it's own distinct JAR.

The vaadin container is started by the skeleton-module. It is perfectly possible to build a navigation with all the necessary routes to the functional units (/routeToView001.../routeToView999) without having further details about them.

However, I don't see, how the started vaadin spring boot container would load the java classes from the independent JARs when navigation occurs in browser. Practical attempts failed. Any ideas?

Comment: "practical attempt failed": please add what you have tried and how it failed. I am also not sure, how this is (only) relevant to vaadin. You will get more and better answers if you open this up to java in general (unless of course the problems you are facing a re vaadin specific).

Comment: Something like this is experimented in this Vaadin Micro Frontend POC: https://vaadin.com/labs/micro-frontend 
Have seen it and is there something missing from that POC to fulfill your use-case?

Answer (score 1):

The Spring Boot integration is by default looking for `@Route` classes within the Java package that contains the `@SpringBootApplication` class. This can be further configured by passing package names to the `@EnableVaadin` annotation.

I haven't tested this in practice, but it might be possible to have a multiple `@EnableVaadin` annotations so that there would be one in each module and through that also provide multiple locations to look for `@Route` classes from. In that case, the `@EnableVaadin` class in each module would also have to register itself  in the same way as any other `@Configuration` by using the regular Spring Boot autoconfiguration mechanism.

Another alternative is that you register route classes manually to the application's route registry (accessed using `ApplicationRouteRegistry.getInstance(new VaadinServletContext(servletContext))`). In that case, you might still need to have at least a dummy `@Route` in the base module since Vaadin might not automatically enable itself in a Spring Boot environment unless at least one `@Route` class is discovered in the regular way.

Comment: Please let us know what you discover so that others can also benefit from your findings!